# Instrument accuracy necessary to distinguish two values

Tags: measurement-error, measurement

Let's say I want to know the size of some shoes, but the size isn't marked. The real size could be any of [35,36,37...50 cm], and the shoes are made so well that their real size is exactly one of these integers when measured with a reference instrument. I measure the shoes with a lower-quality instrument whose measurements include normally-distributed error. I estimated this error previously by measuring objects of known size. What is the **maximum acceptable error to be able to distinguish** whether a shoe is 36 cm and not 35 or 37 cm? Is it just 0.49 cm? In other words how should I specify the necessary performance of the measurement device?

Comment: (1) How reliable do you want your distinctions to be?  (2) How many times are you willing to measure a given shoe?  (3) Please be aware of the difference between *precision* and *accuracy.*  Your reference to the latter at the end of your question suggests there may be some systematic error in the measurement system: is that the case?

Comment: @whuber (1) I would like my distinctions to be correct often, say 95% of the time. (2) I will measure a given shoe once. (3) I estimated my instrument's error previously as the RMS difference between my instrument and the master instrument on a set of objects of known sizes. Let's assume my instrument's error is randomly distributed around the real size and not a systematic bias such as always measuring 0.2 cm too high. I removed the reference to accuracy in the last line.

Comment: @Ed There are several pitfalls there.  The first is that the measurement error is unknown: it has been *estimated* from a calibration experiment.  The second is that it's unlikely all shoe sizes are exact integers--that would be assuming a manufacturing process with no variability at all, which is not plausible.

Comment: Of course you are absolutely correct! The shoes cannot be exactly integer sizes and nothing is stated about the measurement noise distribution. So I just assumed this was a toy model, assumed normally distributed measurement error and tacitly assumed a reasonably accurate estimate of sigma was available. But I think it best to delete my previous comment. Thanks!

Comment: @whuber Let's say the group of shoes was previously measured with a master reference instrument, which has an error which is an order of magnitude lower than that of my lower-quality instrument, and all had sizes that were exact integers. Then the size labels fell off so the actual shoe sizes are unknown.

Comment: Assuming we can have to accept the "rounded low quality estimate" as our estimate then the maximum deviation we can accept is $0.2551$ on the sense that $1.95996*0.2551 < 0.5$.

Comment: @KAE, is that what you are asking though? I would view it as an incomplete answer as it stands. :)

Comment: @whuber does it warrant a new tag anyways? Specially when we have [tag:measurement-error] and [tag:measurement]?

Comment: @Firebug Thank you for finding those.  The benefit of a new tag is that we can make it a synonym of the others (which I will do) and from then on, anyone who wants to tag their post with "metrology" will be able to do so, but the tag will link to the synonymous tags.

Comment: @whuber true, I'll keep that in mind as well, hadn't looked at it from that perspective

Comment: @whuber raises a great point about repeated measurements. If your error term is normally distributed and centered on zero, your measurement tool can be as imprecise as you want, so long as you take enough measurements - the mean of the measurements will approach the true size with enough repeated measures. Repeated applications of an accurate but imprecise tool will essentially fix the precision problem.

Comment: @Nuclear Thank you for your comment, which is to the point.  I just wish to observe that the Normality assumption is unnecessary; having a finite measurement variance suffices. And if one uses the median of the measurements, then literally *any* distribution with a (unique) median of zero will do.

Comment: @NuclearWang In the real-world problem that I am (over) simplifying here, repeated measurements are not possible, but this would indeed be a good approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming we can have to accept the "*rounded low quality estimate*" as our estimate then the maximum standard deviation we can accept is $0.2551$ on the sense that $(1.95996 * 0.2551)<0.5$. 
This would allows us to somewhat approximately ensure that the *"distinctions to be correct often, say 95% of the time"*. 
Just to be clear: if our high-quality instrument is amazing accurate (say, a standard deviation of $0.001$), then having a "relative reference" to it is a bit misleading. It is more relevant to draw a performance threshold based on translating the threshold to our actual needs to make a decision and/or make direct comparison between the two standard deviations (or variances).

Comment: Can you please help me understand your last sentence? The _actual need to make a decision_ is telling the sizes apart with the low-quality instrument, I think, so your 0.2551 answer seems to fit. Is your point that if the high-quality instrument is _amazingly accurate_, it's basically truth?

Comment: Yes, correct; therefore using it as the baseline is not relevant in terms of a relative comparison as it has "no measurement error".